# Outlook search for multiple words in same reply email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search

I have two words "yellow" and "car". I need to search these words in all emails, but "yellow" and "car" must be in same reply.

Comment: And they can be in any order and not necessarily contiguous, so you're just looking for the presence of two different words?  What field are you searching in (e.g., body vs. subject, or anywhere, and one word can be in the subject and the other in the body)?

Comment: Searching in body and two words must be in same body.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Advance Find to achieve this: Add following criterias

[image]

Refer to this official article for more details: [Find a message or item with Instant Search](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-a-message-or-item-with-instant-search-69748862-5976-47b9-98e8-ed179f1b9e4d)